# JQuery addClass screen orientation

Tags: jquery

I've been putting a website together and I've noticed that some of my jquery 'addclass' and on 'hover' aren't being applied or removed when the screen orientation changes.

For example I have a transparent navigation bar for desktop and a full background colour on mobile and at times, when I change the orientation of my device, the background would still be full colour instead of changing back to transparent.

I have included all the neccessary things to make my website responsive - but can't seem to understand why my JQuery is iffy, as such.

If it helps, this is my JQuery below.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if (windowWidth > 991) {
    //CHANGE LOGO ON HOVER
    $('.navbar-light').hover(function () {
        $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-fill.png');
    }, function () {
        $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-trans.png');
        });
    //TOGGLE SCROLLED
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var $nav = $(".navbar-light");
        $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
    });
    // SHRINK LOGO 
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var $nav = $(".logo-desk");
        $nav.toggleClass('shrink', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
    });
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
            //CHANGE LOGO
            $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-fill.png');
            //CHANGE TEXT COLOUR
            $('.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link').css('color', '#494949');
            //CHANGE GIT TEXT COLOUR
            $('.git-container .git-title').css('color', '#494949');
            //ON HOVER CHANGE LOGO
            $('.navbar-light').hover(function () {
                $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-fill.png');
            });
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
            $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-trans.png');
            $('.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link').css('color', '#FFF');
            $('.git-container .git-title').css('color', '#FFF');
            $('.navbar-light').hover(function () {
                $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-fill.png');
            }, function () {
                $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-trans.png');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Look for the [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) event.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thank you